# return a promise of an ongoing asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

I'm trying to launch simultanuously many asynchrnous functions. Some of them make some http calls and I obviously don't want to make the same call multiple times. So, how can this be done using ES6 Promises and if not, what machanism would you recommend to deal with this kind of situations.

Example of the issue:

```
const func1 = () => async1();

const func2 = () => async2().then(async1);

return Promise.all([func1(), func2()]);
```

async1 and async2 are asynchronous functions returning Promises.
The issue is how to deal with three situations :

- func1 and func2 launch async1 in the same time
- func2 launches async1 while async1 is an ongoing asynchronous call in func2
- async1 is launched by func2 after async1 has already been resolved by func1

The last situation is the only one I call deal with right now to prevent same calls from launching multiple times.

Comment: @charlietfl `async1` will be called twice in the sample code

Comment: Why you don't just call `func2` without `then(async1)`?

Comment: @codtex beacuse func1 and func2 are simplified in the example above and in real life they are functions that can be called alone and within Promise.all. So I need I guess some kind of incapsulation of those async functions to not be called when they already have been called or wait if another function is waiting a response..

Comment: Situation is  oversimplified to point we need to ask too many questions. In particular what would differ in async1() if called in func1 or func2? You can cache the promise but not sure if it needs complex cache or very simple one

Comment: @charlietfl is right, but I get your point anyway. In my opinion is better to rethink your logic design and avoid calling one async function from other functions multiple times. Otherwise something else I suggest is to write a simple wrapper class of Promise and set a `running` property (for example), when working with this object you can always check this property before executing. I can write u a simple example if this conception is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse a promise object any time so if you store a request promise the first time it gets called you can return the stored promise on subsequent calls and avoid making multiple requests to same resource

```js
const async1 = (() => {
  let promise;

  return (arg) => {
    console.log(arg, ' = ', promise ? 'Cached request' : 'New request');
    promise = promise || new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 500));
    return promise.then(()=>arg);
  }

})()

Promise.all([async1(1),async1(2)]).then(res=>console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right you want to ensure `async1` in your example will not be called twice.

The easy and (quite low)-level of achieving that is [memoization](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-memoize-in-javascript-51d07d19430e).

Say with lodash's [`_.memoize()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#memoize) it would be

```
const async1 = _.memoize(async1, () => 1)
// wrapping func1 and func2 is not actually required in this case
const func1 = _.memoize(() => async1()); 
const func2 = _.memoize(() => async2().then(async1));
return Promise.all([func1(), func2()]);
```

Beware since you are unable to transparently switch from memoized to _un_memoized implementations on fly.

[UPD] since memoization relies on arguments passed you may need to pass `resolver` callback. Say in your case `async1` may either got zero arguments or something coming from previous promise(when used in `.then`). So arguments are different but since we know all arguments don't matter we can pass resolver that returns constant as a key(say, '1')